# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page “~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've this ActionResult:

```
[EncryptedActionParameter]
[CheckExternalUserRegisterSigned]
public ActionResult ExpedienteIIT(int idExpediente)
{
    ExpedienteContainerVM model = this.GetExpedienteVMByIdExpediente(idExpediente);
    return View("ExpedienteIIT", model);
}
```

ExpedientIIT View:
https://jsfiddle.net/pq16Lr4q/

_Layout.cshtml:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ksvav43/

So when I return the view I got this error:

[image]

I tried to put console.logs to see if the view is rendered but is not rendered...

Ok the error is here:

```
@model PortalSOCI.WEB.ViewModels.IIT.ExpedienteContainerVM


    @{
        ViewBag.Title = String.Format(PortalSOCI.WEB.Resources.ExpedienteIIT.TituloExpedienteIIT, Model.Expediente.NumeroExpediente);
    }

    @section JavaScript  /// <-------------------- ERROR
    {
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)
    @
```

Can you please help me.

Comment: Can you show us your `Layout.cshtml` and the `ExpedienteIIT.cshtml` ?

Comment: So long files... :(

Comment: You could strip out all the irrelevant stuff. Try OJ Raqueño's answer or mine. If it doesn't work, try to provide the files (even if they are very long)

Comment: Ok give me a sec

Comment: out-of-topic but, i'm a bit confused about why you did that ?

    section JavaScript
    {
        Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)
    }

Why is your javascript code contained in the ViewBag ? Can you give us more info about what you indent to do with that JavaScript section ?

Comment: Your `@section JavaScript { .. }` makes no sense, but the error is because you do not have `@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)` in your layout (show the relevant code in your question, not links to images of it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:
After reading your code, i feel like

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

should be

```
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
```

an other thing that I think will give you trouble is the fact that you define your "JavaScript" section in the body. This means that if any of your views you forget to add that

```
@section JavaScript
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.message)
}
```

you'll get a `Section JavaScript not defined` error. In your case, feels like the section's definition should be in the `_layout.cshtml`.

This error most likely means that you have defined the JavaScript section but have not rendered it anywhere. 
You need to call `@RenderSection("JavaScript")` somewhere in your layout.cshtml

the

```
@section JavaScript
{
}
```

will let you create a section called "JavaScript", but to actually "print" the content of this section to the output HTML file (that will be sent to the client) you need to call `@RenderSection("JavaScript")`. The content of the section will be printed where the call to `RenderSection` is located.

Comment: you mean __ayout.cshtml?

Comment: I did and Section not defined: "JavaScript". :S

Comment: You called it AFTER you defined the section right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the missing section inside your `ExpedienteIIT` view. According to the error message, that missing section is `JavaScript`.

Code sample, put this at the bottom of your view:

```
@section JavaScript
{
    // put javascript here
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you for providing a code sample of your views. There is a mismatch between how the JavaScript section in your layout page is defined and how it is being included in your view.

To fix this, do either one of the following:

- In your `_Layout` page, change `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` to `@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)`, OR
- In your `ExpedienteIIT` view, change `@section JavaScript` to `@section scripts`

The important thing is that the two should match.

Comment: I thought your code would define the section, no ? Did i misunderstand something ?